# classed based ViewList (page not found)

Tags: django

I am getting `Page not found (404)` when i visit `job/list/`. 
I am getting details with `job/my-slug`. It works but not `JobInfoList`. Am I missing something? thanks

urls

```
url(r'^job/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', login_required(JobInfoDetail.as_view()), name='jobinfo_detail'),
url(r'^job/list/$', login_required(JobInfoList.as_view()), name='job_list'),
```

Views

```
class JobInfoDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "jobinfo"
    model = JobInfo

class JobInfoList(ListView):
    context_object_name = "job_list"
    model = JobInfo

    def get_queryset(self):
        return JobInfo.objects.filter(company__userprofile__user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order of your regex, as your `jobinfo_detail` is capturing `job/list/`:

```
url(r'^job/list/$', login_required(JobInfoList.as_view()), name='job_list'),
url(r'^job/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', login_required(JobInfoDetail.as_view()), name='jobinfo_detail'),
```